# Assignment to a string variable in which is another variable

Tags: string, variables

Hi i have this controler in Yii2 which render me view. Then i can write in console yii generator/generate example example and then This action generate me skeleton od model and controller which i have in my views. This is code

```
<?php

namespace console\controllers;

use yii\console\Controller;

class GeneratorController extends Controller {

    private $viewControllerPath = "rest/modules/crm/v1/controllers/";
    private $viewModelPath = 'rest/modules/crm/v1/models/';

    public function actionGenerate($className, $modelClass) {

        $controller = $this->renderFile('@app/views/generator/restController.php', ['className' => $className, 'modelClass' =>
            $modelClass]);
        file_put_contents(\Yii::getAlias($this->viewControllerPath . $className . 'Controller' . '.php'), $controller);

        $model = $this->renderFile('@app/views/generator/restModel.php', ['className' => $className, 'modelClass' => $modelClass]);
        file_put_contents(\Yii::getAlias($this->viewModelPath . $className . 'Model' . '.php'), $model);
    }
}`
```

And this is this view:

```
`
    <?php
echo "<?php\n";
?>

namespace rest\modules\<?= $modelClass ?>\v1\models;


use common\models\<?= $modelClass ?>\<?= $className ?> as CommonModel;

class <?= $className ?> extends CommonModel {

}`
```

The last think what i should to do is put mz variable $modelClass in this path

```
private $viewControllerPath = "rest/modules/crm/v1/controllers/";
```

instead of crm. Then my model and controler will be appear in in appropriate folders. 
I try to do this but it isnt work:

```
private $viewControllerPath = "rest/modules/'.$modelClass.'/v1/controllers/";
```

Anyone can help me? Maybe i can use __constructor there but i dont know how to do it

Answer (score 1):

Just replace `crm` word of your variables with `$modelClass` inside your `actionGenerate` function like this:

```php
public function actionGenerate($className, $modelClass) {
    // replacing 'crm' with $modelClass
    if( ! empty($modelClass) ) {
        $this->viewControllerPath = str_replace ( 'crm' , $modelClass , $this->viewControllerPath );
        $this->viewModelPath = str_replace ( 'crm' , $modelClass , $this->viewModelPath );
    }

    $controller = $this->renderFile('@app/views/generator/restController.php', ['className' => $className, 'modelClass' =>
        $modelClass]);
    file_put_contents(\Yii::getAlias($this->viewControllerPath . $className . 'Controller' . '.php'), $controller);

    $model = $this->renderFile('@app/views/generator/restModel.php', ['className' => $className, 'modelClass' => $modelClass]);
    file_put_contents(\Yii::getAlias($this->viewModelPath . $className . 'Model' . '.php'), $model);
}
```